# Why does the if statement in Android Studio (Kotlin) require an else statement?

Tags: android, kotlin

I was surprised by the loss of colors in the RecyclerView while scrolling. I started with a simple if statement, and after testing, I had to add an else statement.

```
if(dataSet[position].status<=2) { //The default color (R.color.green) is set in xml
    val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.primaryDarkColorInactive)
    viewHolder.item.setBackgroundColor(color)
}
```

```
val colorRes = if (dataSet[position].status <= 2) {
    R.color.primaryDarkColorInactive
} else {
    R.color.green
}
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, colorRes)
viewHolder.item.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

I still can't understand what is wrong with the simple if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that it is a **recycler** view. It reuses views that have scrolled off the screen. The view that you're getting in the `onBindView` function is one that may have already been used before, so if you're changing background colors, it may no longer have the color that was initially defined in XML. Anything that you change in `onBindView` should always be changed because there can be no assumption that you are getting a freshly created view from XML.